# add image data to http message body

Tags: html, c, http

I created a simple server program in c using sockets.I'm accessing it with the browser.
program description:if a browser sends a request server will send red.html file.so,the browser need image.png file .then,it'll send another request to server.now,server send imagesend.txt file(it contains headers for image and base64 image data).
when i access it from  browser,it successfully received html file and sent another request to get image.png .then received imagesend.txt.but the browser showing the image like the data is corrupted.

server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(1);
}



int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
if(argc<2)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Port No not provided.\n");
    exit(1);
}
int sockfd,newsockfd,portno,n;
char buffer[1500000];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
socklen_t clilen;
sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(sockfd<0)
{
    error("Opening Socket");
}
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno=atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);
if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    error("Binding");
listen(sockfd,5);
int i=0;
while(1)
{
clilen= sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr ,&clilen);
if(newsockfd<0)
    error("Accept");



    bzero(buffer,1500000);
    n=read(newsockfd,buffer,1000);
    if(n<0)
        error("read");
    printf("%s:%d:%s\n",inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr),(int)ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port),buffer);

    bzero(buffer,1500000);
    FILE *fp;
    /*if(i==1)
    {
        fp=fopen("imagesend.txt","r");
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    int size=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer,1,size,fp);
    n=write(newsockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    }*/
    if(i==0)
        fp=fopen("red.html","r");
    if(i==1)
        fp=fopen("imagesend.txt","r");
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    int size=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer,1,size,fp);
    n=write(newsockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if(n<0)
        error("write");
    close(newsockfd);
    i++;
    if(i>1)
        break;
}

close(sockfd);
close(newsockfd);
return 0;       
}
```

red.html

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length:100000 
Content-Type:text/html

<html>
<head><title>Sample Image</title></head>
<body>
<img src="image.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

imagesend.txt

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length:150000 
Content-Type:image/png

{Here is the base64 data of my image}
```

I'm using boss linux and the browser is firefox.
i think i have problems  with headers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you always use fixed length for `content-length`? Did you verify that your browser gets what you expect to send, using Wireshark? And also to verify that the browser requests what you expect

Comment: You do not parse the request to extract the filename. The browser might ask for some favicon etc. breaking your serial logic.

Comment: You do not check if all data was read or written. Check return values and handle them accordingly. `write` can return more values than `-1` and `size`. BTW: If you have `size` why do you use `strlen`?

Comment: Yeah I checked my server and browser activities.They are sending and receiving exactly as I expected. But at last image file is not showing correctly.I checked even browsers received data size they are correct.

Comment: If you tell the broswer that you send 1,500,000 bytes, without taking into account how large the image really is, the browser might wait to receive the missing parts...

Comment: I reduced the content-length and tried using wireshark to check packages.they have no have problem.If i put image's base64 data to img src directly it works.but this way it doesn't working.